# MPVolumeView Airplay Button Disappears

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, airplay, mpvolumeview

I have created a custom video player in Swift using `AVPlayer` and am using the `MPVolumeView` for the volume control as well as AirPlay. The views initialize perfectly, but I am running into a case where the AirPlay button disappears inside the `MPVolumeView`.

When the view loads, the `MPVolumeView` is initialized without issues

[image: MPVolumeView Initialization]

When the user selects to use AirPlay, the `MPVolumeView` removes the volume slider and only shows the AirPlay, which is what is expected.

[image: Airplay Enabled]

The problem comes when the user closes the `UIViewController` then opens it again to play another video. The Airplay remains enabled, which is the expected behavior. When the user selects to turn off AirPlay, the video returns to playing on the physical device, but the AirPlay button gets hidden.

[image: Missing AirPlay Button]

I have even attempted setting `showsRouteButton` to true for my `MPVolumeView`, but that has no effect on this. What could be causing the AirPlay button to be hidden in this case? It only occurs if AirPlay is enabled when the user starts playing a video, then turns off AirPlay.

Comment: Same problem. Did you resolve it?

Comment: No I haven't been able to yet.

Comment: Same problem here. Any idea ?

Comment: Did you try volumeView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

Comment: Hi, could you please help, how do you add MPVolume with airplay to custom AVPlayer video player?

Comment: You can use the `AVRoutePickerView` on iOS 11. This offers audio route options and also volume slider.